# Android A LOT OF frame by frame animation and decoding

Tags: android, performance, animation, android-animation

My app should show a bunch of animated images (within a list or grid, ~10-20 images on a screen depending on the screen size). Each of these images can contain a lot of frames (up to 150). Actually these images are gifs initially. I get them as encoded mp4 files (to reduce the data size transferred through the network) and decode them on a device. For decoding I use android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever (it doesn't work well on Samsung devices) and I do it the following way: when I show the current frame I put a new decoding task - actually a task to get the next frame - to a priority queue. Priority depends on the time to which I need to get the next frame. If task "expires" (isn't processed by workers before expected time) I just put to a queue next task and etc. But my algorithm doesn't work well - animations are very slow and buggy (I don't also exclude that my implementation can have some bugs)..

So, here are the questions:
1) Are there any other possibly better ways to decode mp4? 
2) Could someone please give me and advice which algorithm I should use to effectively decode mp4 files, so there weren't any animation lags?
3) I can't use simple AnimationDrawable because of out of memory errors, so how can I effectively manage frames cache?

Thanks!